# HDR images are very toned down in blender?

Tags: hdri

Do you know why imported HDR images get their HIghlights and midtones flattened down so much?

Heres what I mean
https://ibb.co/D14F8zS

Comment: I mean in the world settings tab you could increase the strength to make it brighter

Comment: You should connect your Environment Texture through a _Background Node_ (Add > Shader > Background) before connecting to the _World Output_.

Comment: The previews on HDRI Haven are tone-mapped. https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Prasoon-Ambalathankandy/publication/339786805/figure/fig2/AS:867020207816705@1583725134968/Deformation-of-tone-mapping-space-a-Global-Tone-Mapping-b-Global-and-Local-Tone.png

Comment: Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: I dont see an insert iamge button like it says in the linked post you gave, could you explain how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Correct Node Setup]

The hdris are not like regular image textures, they must be fed through Environment texture rather than Image texture into background node like in the image above.
The difference between Image texture and Environment Texture is:
Image Texture: They apply on geometry.
Environment Texture: It's self explanatory. They apply and affect the scene's world.

Comment: I did use Environment texture following this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6VBkj_I-ONk&ab_channel=CGMatter

And I did open the file in PS to check that it is in fact duller than HDRI haven preview, so I corrected it in PS

But even so, there this weird tint or something applied to the image when in Blender, whats going on here?

I also tried inputting the same nodes you did but it didnt change anything
<a href="https://ibb.co/MnpGWLn"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/6Yb1V5Y/2021-04-02-17h05-09.png" alt="2021-04-02-17h05-09" border="0" /></a>

Comment: I tried implementing a method to add image to forum but it didnt work and ende dup being that mess you see up

Heres the basic link to the image
https://ibb.co/MnpGWLn

Answer (score 0):

Another reason could be the tweaking you did in the PS. HDRI images comes with different level of information like in uncompressed .exr extensions. If it's converted to jpg or png it will lose those information because of compression. It could also be that bit depth of the image was affetcnd which might have dull out the tone.

Try downloading the same image from HDRI haven and with out tweaking try the node setup. Also check the color management in the render settings. Make sure it set to filmic and the contrast level is normal.